# ftplib and pyftpdlib : REST (restart) command not working as expected when uploading file to server

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib, pyftpdlib

I've set up a simple FTP server with pyftpdlib and a client with ftplib. When i let the client script run, it uploads the file correctly as expected.

### pyftpdlib Server code:

```
import logging
from pyftpdlib.handlers import FTPHandler
from pyftpdlib.servers import FTPServer
from pyftpdlib.authorizers import DummyAuthorizer

authorizer = DummyAuthorizer()
authorizer.add_user("test","123","C:\\Users\\Usr\\Desktop\\server_data","elradfmwM")
handler = FTPHandler
handler.authorizer = authorizer
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
connection = ("localhost", 8080)
ftpd = FTPServer(connection, handler)
ftpd.serve_forever()
```

### ftplib Client code #1:

```
import ftplib

ftp = ftplib.FTP()
ftp.connect("localhost",8080)
ftp.login("test","123")

block_size = 128
c_dir = "C:\\Users\\Usr\\Desktop\\client_data"
filename = "test.pdf" # ~ 30Mb

ftp.dir()
myfile = open(c_dir + "\\" + filename , "rb")

ftp.storbinary("STOR " + filename, myfile, blocksize=block_size)

ftp.dir()
ftp.close()
```

Now i wanted to test the `REST` (restart upload/download from a specific position) functionality. So i interrupted the client code while still uploading (simply by closing my command prompt while it was uploading). Next, while the server was still running, i ran the following client code in an attempt to resume the upload from the interrupted position:

### ftplib Client code #2:

```
import ftplib

ftp = ftplib.FTP()
ftp.connect("localhost",8080)
ftp.login("test","123")

block_size = 128
c_dir = "C:\\Users\\Usr\\Desktop\\client_data"
filename = "test.pdf" # ~ 30Mb

ftp.dir()
myfile = open(c_dir + "\\" + filename , "rb")

ftp.voidcmd('TYPE I')
rest_pos = ftp.size(filename)
print(rest_pos)
ftp.storbinary("STOR " + filename, myfile, blocksize=block_size, rest=rest_pos)

ftp.dir()
ftp.close()
```

When i run client code #2 it does upload but it seems it doesn't start at the correct position.

The file size is ca. 30 Mb

Client code #1 uploads correctly (ca 30Mb)

Client code #2 uploads but the file is larger and corrupted (ca 35Mb)

I've compared the output of `rest_pos` with the file size under Windows after interrupting and they do match. So the position `rest` i'm passing to `ftp.storbinary` is the same as under Windows.

I'm fairly new to python and ftp and cant figure out what the issue is. Googled, but couldn't find anything similar.

Any tips/hints would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess i made a silly mistake. In case someone else encounters the same, i had to add `myfile.seek(rest_pos,0)` in Client code # 2 to start reading the file to be sent at the specific position. So it should look like this:

```
import ftplib

ftp = ftplib.FTP()
ftp.connect("localhost",8080)
ftp.login("test","123")

block_size = 128
c_dir = "C:\\Users\\Usr\\Desktop\\client_data"
filename = "test.pdf" # ~ 30Mb

ftp.dir()
myfile = open(c_dir + "\\" + filename , "rb")

ftp.voidcmd('TYPE I')
rest_pos = ftp.size(filename)
print(rest_pos)

myfile.seek(rest_pos,0)

ftp.storbinary("STOR " + filename, myfile, blocksize=block_size, rest=rest_pos)

ftp.dir()
ftp.close()
```